# Adding user override to sshd_config causes ssh_exchange_identification error

Tags: sshd

I wanted to allow SSH TCP forwarding for a specific user, so I added this section to sshd_config:

```
Match User rainmannoodles
    AllowTcpForwarding yes
    TCPKeepAlive yes
```

After that change, I get the following message when connecting:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

If I comment out the Match User block, everything works fine. That block is the last one in the file.

I can't think of any reason for this behavior. What exactly is going on here? Here's the full `-vvv` output:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/rainmannoodles/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/rainmannoodles/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/rainmannoodles/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/rainmannoodles/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Comment: Check the logs on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the logs on the server to see what's going wrong.

I expect sshd is complaining that your configuration file is ill-formed. The option `TCPKeepAlive` cannot be used in a `Match` block, presumably because sshd doesn't support changing the value of the option once authentication has finished (this option is used from the start of the connection, before `Match` conditions can be tested).

Comment: Thanks, that was the problematic option, and I confirmed it in the logs. (On that note, I _really_ wish there was an easy, universal way to just print log (and config, and data) file locations for a given program. Switching distros... ugh...) I also found `sshd -t` which checks the config file for errors _before_ the problems actually take effect, so I'm going to start using that every time I do anything on a remote machine. :)